# Recursive call in a for yield structure in Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion, set

I'm confused about the following Scala code from Coursera. The object of this code is to place n number of queens on a chest board so that no queens are threatened by each other, meaning same row, column or diagonal.

1. How does evaluation of the recursive call `PlaceQueen(k-1)` work in every step from when k =0 to k = n? Is there a recursive call `PlaceQueen(k-1)` happening in the line `yield col::queens`?
2. If `col::queens` appends columns of preceding rows as a list, the output of `yield col::queens` should be a list of columns. But how does it get transformed to a Set of list?

   ```
        object nQueens extends App{

        def queens(n: Int): Set[List[Int]] = {
           def placeQueens(k: Int): Set[List[Int]] =
           if (k == 0) Set(List())
           else
           for {
               queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
               col <- 0 until n
               if isSafe(col, queens)
               } yield col :: queens

           placeQueens(n)
           }

           def isSafe(col: Int, queens: List[Int]): Boolean = {
             val row = queens.length
             val queensWithRows = (row - 1 to 0 by -1) zip queens
             queensWithRows forall {
             case (c, r) => col != c && math.abs(col - c) != row - r
              }
           }


          queens(4)

          }
   ```

Output is:
`Set(List(1,3,0,2), List(2,0,3,1))`

Comment: It helps if you can post code that compiles. I've fixed some of the obvious errors but it's still not correct or complete.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the problems with the code which make it not doing what is intended, answers to your questions are:

> how does it get transformed to a Set of list?

It gets transformed because first collection in the `for` is `Set`. It is set because `Set` is defined to be the return type of `placeQueens`.

`queens <- placeQueens(k-1)`

This also answers your first question:

> Is there a recursive call `placeQueen(k-1)?`

as this is where the recursive call is.

Answer (score 0):

This code has multiple infinite loops.

The `queens` method simple calls itself, which is clearly not correct:

```
def queens(n:Int):Set[List[Int]] = {
  def placeQueens(k:Int):Set[List[Int]] = ???
  def isSafe(col: Int, queens:List[Int]):Boolean = ???

  queens(4)
}
```

The `placeQueens` method also calls itself after a bit of computation:

```
def placeQueens(k:Int):Set[List[Int]] = {
  if (k==0) Set(List())
  else
    for {
      queens <-placeQueens(k-1)
      col <- 0 until n
      if isSafe(col,queens)
    } yield col:: queens

  placeQueens(n)
}
```